# Reactjs custom hook call infinite loop

Tags: infinite-loop, components, fetch

I am creating my first ever self made web development project and have run into an infinite loop. The full project can be found on https://github.com/Olks95/my-dnd/tree/spellbook. So the question is: What causes the loop and how do I fix it?

(The loop happens somewhere in the 2nd item of the 'Playground' component when the ContentSelector - Spellbook is called. The custom hook useHandbook is called in Spellbook and continously calls the API, should obviously only happen once... refresh or click return to stop spamming )

From what I can tell the issue is not in the custom hook itself, as I have made several attempts to rewrite it and an empty dependency array is added to the end of the useEffect(). I will try to explain with example code here.

```js
import { Component1, Component2, Component3 } from './ContentSelector.js';

const components = {
  option1: Component1,
  option2: Component2
  option3: Component3
}

const Playground = (props) => {
  const LeftItem = components['option1']
  const MiddleItem = components['option2']
  const RightItem = components['option3']
  ...
}
```

I wanted to be able to choose what content to put in each element and ended up making a ContentSelector component that has all the content components in one file, and individually imported/exported. This seems like a strange way to do it, but it was the only way I found to make it work. (*Maybe the cause of the loop?*) Since this is still fairly early on in the development the selection is hard coded. The item variables starts with a capital letter so I can later call them as components to render like so:

```
<LeftItem ...some properties... />
```

Playground then returns the following to be rendered:

```js
return(
 <React.Fragment>
  <div className="container">
    <div className="flex-item">
      /* Working select-option to pass correct props to Component1 */
      <div className="content">
        <LeftItem ...some properties... />
      </div>
    </div
    <div className="flex-item">
      /* Currently the same selector that changes the content of the LeftItem */
      <div className="content">
        <MiddleItem ...some properties... />
      </div>
    </div>
    /*RightItem follows the same formula but currently only renders "coming soon..." */
  </div>
 </React.Fragment>
)
```

The Content selector then has the three components where:

Component1: calls a custom hook that only runs once. The information is then sent to another component to render. All working fine.

**Component2: calls a custom hook infinite times, but is expected to work the same way component 1 does...**

Component3: Renders coming soon...

See Component1 and 2 below:

```js
export const Component1 = (props) => {
    const [ isLoading, fetchedData ] = useDicecloud(props.selectedChar);
    let loadedCharacter = null;

    if(fetchedData) {
        loadedCharacter = {
          name: fetchedData[0].Name,
          alignment: fetchedData[0].Alignment,
          /* a few more assignments */
        };
      }

    let content = <p>Loading characters...</p>;

    if(!isLoading && fetchedData && fetchedData.length > 0) {
        content = (
            <React.Fragment>
                <Character 
                    name={loadedCharacter.name}
                    alignment={loadedCharacter.alignment}
                    /* a few more props */ />
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
    return content;
}
```

```js
export const Component2 = (props) => {
    const [ fetchedData, error, isLoading ] = useHandbook('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://dnd5eapi.co/api/spells/?name=Aid')

    let content = <p>Loading spells...</p>;

    if(!isLoading && fetchedData) {
/* useHandbook used to return text to user in a string in some situations */
        if(typeof fetchedData === 'string') {
            content = (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <p> {fetchedData} </p>
                </React.Fragment>
            )
        } else {
            content = (
                <React.Fragment>
                    <Spellbook
/* the component that will in the future render the data from the API called in useHandbook */
                     />
                </React.Fragment>
            )
        }
    }
    return content;
}
```

I have been working on this issue for a few days and it is getting more confusing as I go along. I expected the mistake to be in useHandbook, but after many remakes it does not seem to be. The current useHandbook is very simple as shown below.

```js
export const useHandbook = (url) => {
    const [ isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(false);
    const [ error, setError ] = useState(null);
    const [ data, setData ] = useState(null);

        const fetchData = async () => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            try {
                const res = await fetch(url, {
                    method: "GET",
                    mode: 'cors'
                });
                const json = await res.json();
                setData(json);
                setIsLoading(false);
            } catch(error) {
                setError(error);
            }
        };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []); //From what the documentation says, this [] should stop it from running more than once.
    return [ data, error, isLoading ];
};
```

EDIT: I ran the chrome developer tools with the react extension and saw something that might be useful:

[Image showing Component2 (Spellbook) run inside itself infinite times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYESx.png)

Comment: You might want to post this to Stackoverflow instead of Superuser for better visibility and relevant audience being able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your custom hook `useHandbook's` `useEffect` hook to have URL as dependency, since `useEffect` is similar to `componentWillMount`, `componentDidUpdate` and `componentWillUnmount`, in your case it is `componentDidUpdate` multiple times. So what you can do is.

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
}, [url]);
```

Since there is no need to fetch data agin unless URL is changed

Comment: I tried this before, and tried it again now. The loop is still there. Added an image at the end of the question that shows it is the whole `Component2` (Spellbook) that runs in a loop.
Also if I understand the useEffect correctly, having an empty array takes away the `componentDidUpdate` since an empty array will never change.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. `Component2`'s real name was `Spellbook` which I had also called the rendering component that I had not yet made. It turns out I was calling the component from within itself.

Easy to see in the image at the edit part of the question.